# Segues are not animating as expected

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

Since I've updated Xcode to 4.5, I experience a lot of problems with segue. Sometime, I add some segues that Xcode doesn't detect, event they are set correctly. But now, I have a problem with two segues, they are set as modal, with cross dissolve animations. But they are animating with the default animation. I have deleted, added again, clear cache, but they are still doing the default animation. It's frustrating...

Many thanks

Comment: I have changed their names, an now it gives me "has no segue with identifier " exception with new name, but they correctly set in storyboard...

Comment: I have checked storyboard source and they are correct, too.  <segue destination="8FH-nx-ZLn" kind="modal" identifier="revistas" modalTransitionStyle="crossDissolve" id="Lbe-V6-Xle"/>